# Spring PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and Environment

Tags: java, spring, properties

I want to configure properties for different profiles (production and dev).

That's my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyPlaceholderConfig {

  @Profile(Profiles.PRODUCTION)
  static class ProductionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigure()
    throws IOException {
      PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySources =
      new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
      propertySources.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
      Resource[] resources =
      ObjectArrays.concat(getCommonResources(), getProductionResources(), Resource.class);
      propertySources.setLocations(resources);
      return propertySources;
    }

    private static Resource[] getProductionResources() throws IOException {
      return new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
      .getResources("classpath:properties/production/*.properties");
    }

  }


  @Profile(Profiles.DEV)
  static class DevConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigure()
    throws IOException {
      PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySources =
      new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
      propertySources.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
      Resource[] resources =
      ObjectArrays.concat(getCommonResources(), getDevResources(), Resource.class);
      propertySources.setLocations(resources);
      return propertySources;
    }

    private static Resource[] getDevResources() throws IOException {
      return new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
      .getResources("classpath:properties/dev/*.properties");
    }

  }


  private static Resource[] getCommonResources() throws IOException {
    return new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
    .getResources("classpath:properties/common/*.properties");
  }


}
```

I printed current profile (dev) and loaded files (all have been correcly loaded into Resouce array). I want to use this loaded properties in database config. How to do it?
I used:

```
@Import(PropertyPlaceholderConfig.class)
```

over the class,
and:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

but

```
environment.getProperty("h2.driverClass");
```

or

```
environment.resolvePlaceholders("${h2.driverClass}");
```

doesn't work.

How to use properties loaded by PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer?

I know that I can use @Value with fields but is it possible to avoid creating 15 fields?

Comment: The `Environment` only works if you use `@PropertySource` instead of letting the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. load the configs. Also it is quite a contraption you created just for loading property files.